# Get count in graph traversal

Tags: graph, arangodb, aql

I started learning arangoDB, I took the udemy course to learn the basics of arangoDB. The instructor used flights & airport dataset to teach both named & anonymous graph queries.
One of the queries that he ran to fetch the list of airports was

> FOR airport IN airports
> FILTER airport.city =="San Francisco"
> FILTER airport.vip == true
> FOR v,e,p IN 1..1 OUTBOUND airport flights
> FILTER v._id=="airports/KOA"
> LIMIT 0,10
> return p

what if I want to fetch count of all possible result, what would be the best approach to get the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could encapsulate the query in the `COUNT` function:

```
RETURN COUNT(
    FOR airport IN airports 
        FILTER airport.city =="San Francisco" AND airport.vip == true 
        FOR v,e,p IN 1..1 OUTBOUND airport flights 
            FILTER v._id=="airports/KOA" LIMIT 0,10 
            RETURN 1
)
```

Comment: this is a subquery, I know this. curious is there any better way to get count other than a subquery.

Comment: Embedding a query in `COUNT` or `LENGTH` is the way to count in AQL.